# Workflow for simple static websites

Tags: templates, web, workflow, yeoman, linemanjs

I always used to deploy even single websites with some kind of back-end service, mostly PHP-framework. But ive been lately looking for a better alternative.

I would like to use tools like
Grunt/Gulp with concat, lint, liveReload
SASS

And just upload generated html/css/js to server.

But I would like to have some basic feature for including templates.
So that in /pages/index.html I would have something like <% include partials/header.html %>

I have looked into lineman and yeoman but I couldnt find a solution which would include all the solutions I would like. Esecially the templating, I really dont want to copy-paste any html.

Is there something I missed? Thanks for any insights.

EDIT: Seems like adding Assemble to my yeoman project is way to go. Ill try this tomorow and let you know how it goes:]

Comment: Why you're not using a templating engine like Smarty (http://www.smarty.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, its been this awesome package that got me started. It has all that I needed and works nicely:

https://github.com/raulghm/gulp-assemble

I gotta learn grunt/gulp someday to be able to create and set up things like this :)